# Can Amazon extra charge me for exceeding sustainable zone using Lightsail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I've recently started using Lightsail. I'm currently running on a 3-month free trial that Amazon offers for a 2GB RAM and 1 vCPU Windows instance.

I'm only experiencing with VM's for the moment and using it for personal purposes so I'd really like to take advantage of the free trial to see if it suits me.

However, in the 24-hourish time my instance was running I've noticed it is always slightly above the sustainable zone and into the burstable zone. I've read plenty of articles about burstable but haven't really figured this out:

1. It seems that my instance is running on 0% REMAINING CPU BURST CAPACITY. For every minute I run on 0%, if I wasn't on free trial, I would be charged? Or even for above 0% capacity I would be charged?
2. Can Amazon start charging me extra for the fact I'm always slightly above the sustainable zone, even when I'm in free trial?
3. Can my instance suddenly stop working after a prolonged period of time running in the burstable zone?

Here are screenshots of my instance's metrics:
[image: instance metrics]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the page does not actually say what happens when the burst capacity reaches zero.

The descriptions of burst behaviour appear to match that of the T2-family of Amazon EC2 instances.

The Lightsail pricing makes no mention of an 'Unlimited burst mode', which in EC2 can be used to burst beyond the provided credit balance.

Therefore, it would appear that the Lightsail instance **would simply be limited to operate at a maximum of 20% CPU** when the burst capacity balances reaches zero.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a reasonable assumption but has it been confirmed (empirically or via a support question to AWS)?\